# Mutex understanding

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Can somebody explain to me why this code is bad:

```
int data;
void* worker(void* arg __attribute__((unused))) {
   pthread_mutex_t m;
   pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
      data++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
   }
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);
   return NULL;
}
```

And this is ok:

```
int data;
pthread_mutex_t m;
void* worker(void* arg __attribute__((unused))) {
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
      data++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
   }
   return NULL;
}
// ...
pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL);
// ...
pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);
// ..
```

Do i always need to declare mutex variables globally?

Comment: What is actually meant by bad code?

Comment: It would not work correctly on some inputs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12776593/4593781, this post can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with local `mutex` is that it's only a locally accessible version of the `mutex` ... therefore when a `thread` locks the `mutex` in order to share some globally accessible data, the data itself is not protected, since every other `thread` will have it's own local `mutex` that can be locked and unlocked. It defeats the whole point of mutual exclusion.

I suggest also to think about exception safety. In this particular example you are just doing `data++` in the middle of `mutex` `lock/unlock`. So what if you are putting another statement before `pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);` in the future which can throw a exception. Read about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).